# Three contestants are chosen between five guys for a debate competition

Tags: combinatorics

The following is a high-school math question, and I don't know why my approach didn't give the correct answer.

A debate club is going for a threesome competition, but there are three boys(B) and two girls(G) in the club. Out of gender equality, there must be members of both sexes in a group going for the competition. And, after a group is formed, the three group members must reach a consensus to determine which one of them is going for the first-round debate, which one is the next, and so on. Now what is the number of arrangements for the club to go for the competition?

The answer is $54$, and the solution goes by taking care of 2B1G and 1B2G separately, which is clear to me. But I wonder why we can't answer the question simply by
$$C_1^3\times C_1^2\times C_1^3\times(3!)=108?$$
The first $C_1^3$ stands for a choice between those three boys, $C_1^2$ stands for a choice between those two girls, and the second $C_1^3$ stands for a choice between the remaining three guys in the club. Finally, the factorial is intended for a permutation because we need to determine the sequence for the competition. Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's due to the fact that the second $C^3_1$ creates double cases when we choose the third member. For example, let the boys be $A$, $B$, and $C$ and the girls be $M$ and $N$. Suppose we chose $A$ and $M$ as our first two choices, then we choose $B$ as our third member out of the remaining three. This is equivalent to choosing $B$ as our first member and $A$ as our third member. Hence, we have the same group in both cases, $A$, $M$, and $B$, which is being counted twice giving us twice the number of permutations.